# Declaring Variables and Using Them Elsewhere with Jquery

Tags: jquery

Help! I'm trying to get the background image declared inline in a div (.SlideContent) and get it to put that value in an adjacent OL LI like so:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".banner ul li").each(function() {
        $(this).children('a').each(function() {
            $(this).children('.SlideContent').each(function() {
                var backgroundImage = $(this).css("background-image");
            });
        });
    });
    $(".banner ol.dots").each(function() {
        $(this).children('li.dot').each(function() {
            $(this).css("background-image", backgroundImage);
        });
    });
});
```

When I try this it just populates the OL list items with the same image over and over.

Comment: Without seeing your HTML it's tough to understand what you want, however I can almost guarantee you're over using .each().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var dots = $(".banner ol.dots li.dot");
    $(".banner ul li a .SlideContent").each(function(i) {
        dots.eq(i).css("backgroundImage", $(this).css("backgroundImage"));
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's out of scope - Javascript has function scope, as opposed to block scope. A variable only lives as long as the function lives, unless you create a closure.

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      var backgroundImage = '';
        $(".banner ul li").each(function() {
            $(this).children('a').each(function() {
                $(this).children('.SlideContent').each(function() {
                    backgroundImage = $(this).css("background-image");
                });
            });
        });
        $(".banner ol.dots").each(function() {
            $(this).children('li.dot').each(function() {
                $(this).css("background-image", backgroundImage);
            });
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

if you have array of images that needs to be used in each cycle of your iterations try something like this...

```
var backgroundImage = new Array();
var myIdx = 0;
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(".banner ul li").each(function() {
        $(this).children('a').each(function() {
            $(this).children('.SlideContent').each(function() {
                backgroundImage[myIdx] = $(this).css("background-image");
                myIdx++;
            });
        });
    });
    myIdx = 0;
    $(".banner ol.dots").each(function() {
        $(this).children('li.dot').each(function() {
            $(this).css("background-image", backgroundImage[myIdx]);
            myIdx++;
        });
    });
});
```